# Mongodb and Loopback while deploying on openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, loopbackjs

I am deploying my first loopback application to Openshift. But it is not working. I have created a datasources.local.js file. And made some changes.

datasources.local.js

```
module.exports = {
  myDB: {
    connector: 'loopback-connector-mongodb',
    host: 'mongodb://$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST',
    port: '$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT',
    database: 'even3co',
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'ZWQbMQpvMz-F'
 }
};
```

model-config.json

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Account": {
    "dataSource": "myDB",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

datasources.json

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "myFile": {
    "name": "myFile",
    "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
    "provider": "filesystem",
    "root": "./server/storage"
  }
}
```

And rhc tail  shows an error message

> Account is referencing a dataSource that does not exist: "myDB"

Isn't this the right way???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by upgrading the loopback-boot to version 2.9.0. The issue was with loopback-boot version 2.6.5 and had to modify the connection url.